# CoreBluetooth - Long data on read/write

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm trying send a long data (~2150 bytes) through the readValueForCharacteristic like that:

My characteristics:

```
    self.centralInfoCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:WRITE_CENTRAL_INFO_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
    self.peripheralInfoCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:READ_INFO_PERIPHERAL_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
```

Central requesting the characteristic value:

```
    - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
            if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:READ_INFO_PERIPHERAL_UUID]]){
                [self.discoveredPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
            } else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:WRITE_CENTRAL_INFO_UUID]]){
                [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:[self.myUserInfo transformJsonData] forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
            }
        }
    }
```

When central is requesting exactly 628 bytes, the process is working like a charm! But, when it is requesting 2150 bytes, the next steps occurs:

On peripheral: (this method is called 4 times, where offset = {0, 157, 314, 471})

```
    - (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request{
      if ([request.characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:READ_INFO_PERIPHERAL_UUID]){    
          if (request.offset > peripheralInfoCharacteristicData.length) {
              [peripheral respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorInvalidOffset];
              return;
          }
          request.value = [peripheralInfoCharacteristicData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(request.offset, peripheralInfoCharacteristicData.length - request.offset)];
          [self.peripheralManager respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];   
      }
```

After that on Central:

```
   - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
      if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:READ_INFO_PERIPHERAL_UUID]){
          // characteristic.value is equal 628. It is wrong! Should be 2150
          // So I can't deserialize the NSData
      }
    }
```

So, what is wrong? It is not possible pass >628 bytes on readValueCharacteristic?

When I using writeValueCharacteristic, the didReceiveWriteRequests isn't called, just when I pass 628- bytes.

The `peripheralInfoCharacteristicData` variable is instantiate on `viewDidLoad`:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                                                                                  @"ID": self.userId,
                                                                                  @"U": self.userNameStr
                                                                                  }];
    if (self.userPhotoImg) [dictionary setObject:[self imageToNSString:self.userPhotoImg] forKey:@"F"];
    peripheralInfoCharacteristicData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
   // peripheralInfoCharacteristicData.length = 2150
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the `peripheralInfoCharacteristicData` variable doesn't change between calls, otherwise you run into problems if the data is not the same.

Comment: @Cristik This variable doesn't changing. During each call only the `request.value` variable is changing. Which method do you think is changing it?

Comment: Where and how are you populating the contents of that variable?

Comment: @Cristik Post edited